# How do I get JS Console response code from execute_script with Python+Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I am sending a JS fetch request in the Chrome dev console with the selenium `execute_script()` function. The request works as expected, but I would like to create a function that verifies the response is a 403 status code. Is there a built-in Selenium function/library that I can use to extract that status code/response into an object or value that I can assert against?

This is my current code to send the request:

```
send_request = """
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: '',
  headers: headers,
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.status)
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result)
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    }
)"""
context.browser.execute_script(send_request)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need execute_async_script because fetch is async:

```
status = context.browser.execute_async_script("""
  let [resolve] = arguments
  fetch(url).then(r => resolve(r.status))
""")
```